# Math.Clamp won't limit my position until movement is ceased

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

The program is in a top down view, with Y going up (or forward depending upon how you see it), and X going from left to right based on the camera view. I am attempting to set the minimum and maximum values of my main character's x/y-axis movement through the float "clamp", under the struct "Mathf".

When my ship passes the minimum/maximum value on either axis, it doesn't stop it. If you release the movement key after passing the point, the character will appear directly on the minimum/maximum point that was passed. See the gif below.

[Gif here http://gph.is/22fdHv4](http://gph.is/22fdHv4)

Below is the current script running for both player movement and the boundary, attached to the main character.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShipMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float xMin;
public float xMax;
public float yMin;
public float yMax;
public float speed = 2f;
public float shotSpeed = 4f;
public float nextFire1;
public float nextFire2;
//Animator anim;
public GameObject shot;
public Transform shotSpawn;
public float fireRate = 0.25f;

void Start () {

//anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void FixedUpdate () {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position = new Vector3 (
            Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, xMin, xMax ),
            Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.y, yMin, yMax),
            0.0f
        );

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    } 
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    } 
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        transform.Translate (Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        //anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    } else {
        //anim.SetBool ("moving", false);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space) && Time.time > nextFire1)
    {
        nextFire1 = Time.time + fireRate;
        Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.X) && Time.time > nextFire2) {
        nextFire2 = Time.time + fireRate;
        Instantiate (shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
    }

    if (gameObject == null) {
        Application.Quit ();
      }
   }
}
```

Although I am not sure, I suspect it may have something to with the way I am controlling the movement. I have had issues with what I have written in the past, especially with animations and moving left/right while also moving up/down. (Hence why I have all of the animation code commented out, and I am using a Capsule instead of a ship).

If anything else is needed, I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the position after you calculate that it is inside your bounds. This will also account for pressing multiple keys at the same time.

```
Vector3 newPosition;

if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
    newPosition = transform.position + Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    //anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
} 

GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position = new Vector3 (
    Mathf.Clamp (newPosition.x, xMin, xMax ),
    Mathf.Clamp (newPosition.y, yMin, yMax),
        0.0f
);
```

Comment: sorry for the late response - will test when i get home

Comment: Well it has been a busy few weeks! I haven't forgotten! This worked perfectly. The only thing I am failing to understand is why it would continue outside of the bounds until I release the movement key, not reset continually back to the bounding location.

Comment: Strange. Can I take a look at your updated code?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

I can observe more than one reason. May be **Before After**, may be this is due to `vector3.x` or `vector3.y` cannot be modified in c#.

First of all kindly change `FixedUpdate` to `Update`. And from now please don't get inputs in `FixedUpdate` otherwise you will get Jerks in getting input. Now Replace your whole `FixedUpdate` to these lines of code.

```
void Update(){

    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x + Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed,xMin,xMax), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y + Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed,yMin,yMax), transform.position.z);

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") || Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))
        anim.SetBool ("moving", true);
    else
        anim.SetBool ("moving", false);

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space) && Time.time > nextFire1){
        nextFire1 = Time.time + fireRate;
        Instantiate(shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.X) && Time.time > nextFire2) {
        nextFire2 = Time.time + fireRate;
        Instantiate (shot, shotSpawn.position, shotSpawn.rotation);
    }

    if (gameObject == null) {
        Application.Quit ();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.  That's because you clamp the values *before* accounting for the keys being pressed.  So the position is clamped to the bounds, then the player moves out of bounds.